# entityState no change to Modified when I use ko.extenders

Tags: validation, knockout.js, breeze

I used `ko.extenders` to validate in client, but this produced that `entityState` didn't change to `Modified` when I changed that property.

I used the code example in ["Live Example 2: Adding validation to an observable"](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

Steps of test:
1. I had loaded an entity in a form.
2. I edited a property (with ko.extenders.required) of entity
3. The entityState = `Unchanged`
4. But when I edited a property (without ko.extenders.required) the entityState change to `Modified`

Please any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line:

```
this.lastName = ko.observable(last).extend({ required: "" });
```

and I had used the next lines:

```
this.lastName = ko.observable(last);
this.lastName.extend({ required: "" });
```

And all work perfectly.